# Query for converting a column of numbers matching a regex in MySQL

Tags: mysql, update, regular-expression, replace

I have a column which contains string values of the format e.g `AB12345678` - two letters followed by 8 numeric digits.

I need to write a MySQL query to insert a `5` before each set of 4 digits thus `AB12345678` becomes `AB5123455678`.

I'm close, the following works for one value in the column, but not for multiple values - all values are written with the same first value encountered it seems.

```
SELECT @twoeight := os_grid_ref FROM projects WHERE os_grid_ref REGEXP '[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}';
SELECT @prefix1 := SUBSTR(@twoeight,1,2);
SELECT @part1 := SUBSTR(@twoeight,3,4);
SELECT @part2 := SUBSTR(@twoeight,7,4);
UPDATE projects SET os_grid_ref=CONCAT(@prefix1,'5',@part1,'5',@part2) WHERE os_grid_ref REGEXP '[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}';
```

What do I need to adjust so that the query can modify each value in the column individually.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change those things in place:

```
UPDATE projects
    SET os_grid_ref = CONCAT(
         SUBSTR(os_grid_ref,1,2), '5',
         SUBSTR(os_grid_ref,3,4), '5',
         SUBSTR(os_grid_ref,7,4)
                            )
    WHERE ...;
```

If the table is huge, Update will take a long time.  Leave off the `WHERE` clause if you want to change very row.

If you are changing the value as you fetch, then

```
SELECT ..., 
        CONCAT(...as above ...) AS new_ref
    FROM projects
    WHERE ...;
```

If you expect to do variations of this, consider writing a `STORED FUNCTION` to do the `CONCAT`.

Comment: +1 and accepted. Brilliant thanks so much. For my `WHERE` clause, I modified my original regex to now use: `WHERE os_grid_ref REGEXP '^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}$';` - which has the line anchors `^` and `$`  - this ensures that any entries already converted don't get converted again - so that the update query is idempotent after the first conversion, the regex acts as a conditional check in that regard.

Comment: @therobyouknow - That regexp is equivalent to `'^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{8}$'`.  This would also prevent double-conversion, but would not check for the full pattern:  `WHERE LENGTH(os_grid_ref) = 10`,  (and other possibilities)